# Lost Schengen visa. Is it possible to travel within the Schengen area with police documents and the receipt of Permesso di soggiorno from Italy?

Tags: visas, schengen, lost-documents

My bag was stolen in Milan and I lost my passport and the Schengen visa. I filed a police complaint and got a new passport from the embassy. I also applied for the Permesso di soggiorno and I have the receipt. Can I travel within the Schengen area with these documents alone? Will there be any problems?
New passport, photo copy of the visa, police documents, receipt of Permesso from Italy.

Answer (score 2):

During my last trip to Europe, one member of our group lost her documents. The tour guide mentioned that you may have troubles with leaving Schengen area without your passport and visa. But she also said that to be sure everything is fine you need to contact the embassy of your country (which you did as you already have your new passport) AND the embassy of the country that issued your visa. The experience of other tourists shows that restoring the visa takes not so much time. Good luck with that!